# i need an excel formual that watches a column type

Tags: excel, nested, formulas

Ok to paint a picture.

A sheet named bob another sheet named joe.

These sheets will have a column listed as type. it will be say E3 thru E100
in this column there will be either W, CPC, Or AMW.

A separate sheet named main will be looking at these sheets bob and joe and the column type E3 thru E100.

if the column has a w then it would count that as 1

if it has a cpc then is would count that as 1

if it has amw then it would count that as one.

And for each time it sees one of these it will added it up and tally a total back on the sheet name main.

This formula would be written 2 times for each person so it would show how many warranty jobs they did or how many customer paid jobs they did or how many aftermarket warranty job they did.

I am trying to make my job easier when i import a report from work.
can this be done is the question?

Thank you in advanced and please beware i am an idiot when it comes this stuff.

I am an ASE technician managing i group of techs and trying to make my reports not take as long as they do now which is all day so thank you in advance

Mike

Comment: adding sample data from your sheets will be helpful for us to help you. With your desired output too

Answer (score 0):

It's sounds terrible, in first instance I do believe that you are trying to Count 3 codes, but unable to understand for whom,, as described later,, so better post either screen shots or sample data, help me to solve the problem.